# Raspberry pi - get-pip.py error

Tags: python, opencv, debian, pip, raspberry-pi2

I'm working on a Raspberry pi 2 with piface. I'm trying to install openCV by following this steps : [click here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/02/23/install-opencv-and-python-on-your-raspberry-pi-2-and-b/). When I try doing the step 6 (install pip), I got the following error :

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo python get-pip.py

        Exception:
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/tmp/tmpxtbKBh/pip.zip/pip/basecommand.py", line 211, in main
            status = self.run(options, args)
          File "/tmp/tmpxtbKBh/pip.zip/pip/commands/install.py", line 305, in run
            wb.build(autobuilding=True)
          File "/tmp/tmpxtbKBh/pip.zip/pip/wheel.py", line 705, in build
            self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
          File "/tmp/tmpxtbKBh/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 334, in prepare_files
            functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))
          File "/tmp/tmpxtbKBh/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 321, in _walk_req_to_install
            more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
          File "/tmp/tmpxtbKBh/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 409, in _prepare_file
            req_to_install, finder)
          File "/tmp/tmpxtbKBh/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 365, in _check_skip_installed
            finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, self.upgrade)
          File "/tmp/tmpxtbKBh/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 486, in find_requirement
            all_versions = self._find_all_versions(req.name)
          File "/tmp/tmpxtbKBh/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 404, in _find_all_versions
            index_locations = self._get_index_urls_locations(project_name)
          File "/tmp/tmpxtbKBh/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 378, in _get_index_urls_locations
            page = self._get_page(main_index_url)
          File "/tmp/tmpxtbKBh/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 818, in _get_page
            return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
          File "/tmp/tmpxtbKBh/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 928, in get_page
            "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
          File "/tmp/tmpxtbKBh/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 477, in get
            return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
          File "/tmp/tmpxtbKBh/pip.zip/pip/download.py", line 373, in request
            return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
          File "/tmp/tmpxtbKBh/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
            resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
          File "/tmp/tmpxtbKBh/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
            r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
          File "/tmp/tmpxtbKBh/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 46, in send
            resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
          File "/tmp/tmpxtbKBh/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
            timeout=timeout
          File "/tmp/tmpxtbKBh/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
            body=body, headers=headers)
          File "/tmp/tmpxtbKBh/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 344, in _make_request
        self._raise_timeout(err=e, url=url, timeout_value=conn.timeout)
      File "/tmp/tmpxtbKBh/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 314, in _raise_timeout
        if 'timed out' in str(err) or 'did not complete (read)' in str(err):  # Python 2.6
    TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type Error)
```

I tried to do the step 7 but I got the barely the same message (install virtualenv) :

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 290, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1178, in prepare_files
    url = finder.find_requirement(req_to_install, upgrade=self.upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 194, in find_requirement
    page = self._get_page(main_index_url, req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_page
    session=self.session,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 694, in get_page
    req, link, "connection error: %s" % exc, url,
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type Error)

Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

I'm trying to solve this problem since 2 days, so if anyone can help me...

Please.

Don't hesitate if you need more information. I also need to apologize for my english, I'm a swiss student...

Comment: What does `python --version` give you?

Comment: It gives me Python 2.7.9 @Holt